# Load a specific option of SELECT tag while loading a template in Marionette

Tags: marionette, ejs

I'm trying to load the specific value of a drop down select tag when I'm loading that html inside the Marionette LayoutView.

The situation is

This is my html template which is passed to a Marionette LayoutView with a Model

```
<div class="span3">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="registeredIndicator">Registered</label>
        <select class="input-medium" id="registeredIndicator">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

In that model a value registered indicator is retrieved as true or false.
My Goal is - When this template is rendered I want to display the value which is retrieved i.e. if its `true`, `registeredIndicator` should be `Yes` and vice-versa.

I accomplished this thing with help of jQuery inside the `onRender` function of LayoutView like

```
if(true === this.model.get('registeredIndicator')){
    this.$('#registeredIndicator option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
}
```

but I got lot of drop downs in the HTML and it would not be a efficient way to check each every one with jquery.

I tried using if else inside the HTML with <%%> but this was not fruitful and is not correct also.

Is there any another approach available in which i can manipulate the data inside the template itself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the conditional below should work:

```
<div class="span3">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="registeredIndicator">Registered</label>
        <select class="input-medium" id="registeredIndicator">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option <%= registeredIndicator ? "selected" : "" %> value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Specifically I added `<%= registeredIndicator ? "selected" : "" %>` to your template.

Comment: Thank You for the answer its working. For an expected 'false' value i just did this  

<%= !registeredIndicator ? "selected" : "" %>

Comment: Also is there any way to achieve this thing when expected value is not true/false and something like 'onLease', 'onRent', 'forBuy' etc.. 

So in this condition, can we modify the if shorthand

Comment: Yeah. You would do the same kind of thing. Just set the conditional expression to test for the equality you care about. Something like: `<%= value == "onLease" ? "selected" : "" %>`

Comment: @AndrewHubbs What does `<%= value == "onLease" ? "selected" : "" %>` syntax means: `? : ""`. Thx